# magento 2 change admin label

Tags: magento-2.2.5, translate

i want to change magento admin sidebar labels for eg "catalog" to "My products"

is there way to do it without changing core files i tried using translation by adding files in "app/design/adminhtml/default/custom/locale/en_US"

**translate.csv**

but it does not seems working

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom module and create menu.xml file under etc/adminhtml directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <update id="Magento_Catalog::catalog" title="My Products" translate="title" module="Magento_Catalog" sortOrder="20" dependsOnModule="Magento_Catalog" resource="Magento_Catalog::catalog"/>
     </menu>
</config>
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Hey, Have you tried this solution?